# Shared Preference value returns null

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have an application in which I am using shared preference. I debugged my application and realised that the string value is getting stored inside the shared preference. But when I am retrieving the value in some other activity, it returns null

Refer my code below:

**Activity1:**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); 

editor.putString("NewEmailID", "example@xyz.com");
```

**Activity2:**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String strEmailID = preferences.getString("NewEmailID", null);
if (strEmailID != null){
   lblEmailID.setText(strEmailID);
}
```

As you can see in Activity1, I am storing the string value in the shared preference, and in Activity2, I'm retrieving the value from it.

Therefore, `strEmailID` returns null.

Am I doing something wrong over here?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you calling `commit()` or `apply()` on `editor` after the `putString()` call in `Activity1`?

Comment: have you apply `editor.apply()` method?

Comment: yes I have written editor.commit();

Comment: when storing data , you have to commit. add editor.commit() when save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting something in Editor you must use apply or commit.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); 

editor.putString("NewEmailID", "example@xyz.com");
editor.apply();
```

Apply is asynchronous it doesn't block tread and doesn't return true or false. This operation works faster because instantly change values in memory and write it later in other thread. But on few values have same performance comparing to using commit that writes in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); 
editor.putString("NewEmailID", "example@xyz.com");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **editor.commit();** when you save the value into SharePreferences.